# Is storing passwords hashed with the email more secure than without?

Tags: php, passwords, md5

Say I have a platform, and I want to store a password.

Is it more secure to store the password prefixed with the users email, then to hash it then just hashing the password?

Example,

```
$hash = md5($email.$password);
```

Rather then just

```
$hash = md5($password);
```

Then to store the variable $password.

Comment: if user can change her email, then her password don't will be valid no?

Comment: your talking about salts.

Comment: I would say it ***could*** be considered more secure until someone figured out you were salting all passwords with an email.  At which point your salt is worthless.  Then you run into issues like capitalization, changing email addresses, etc.

Use a randomly generated salt, not an easy to figure out one like an email.  Salting gets you a ***lot*** more security than tacking on something not random.

Comment: @Oscargeek you need to enter a password when you change your email, so it can be regenerated with the new email.

Comment: Better to use password_hash()/password_verify() which uses a more secure hashing algorithm, and a more secure random salt